# Shopware 6 Api get product listing by category id with product properties

Tags: shopware

I want to fetch a product listing by category. The documentation says that I can also fetch the product properties: https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/cf2592a37b40b-fetch-a-product-listing-by-category

This is my call:

```js
    const params = {
      limit: 100,
      includes: {
        product: ['id', 'name', 'properties', 'propertyIds'],
        property_group_option: ['id', 'name', 'group'],
        property_group: ['id', 'name'],
      },
      associations: {
        properties: {
          associations: {
            group: [],
          },
        },
      },
    };
  const result = await $axios.post(
    $axios.defaults.baseURL + '/product-listing/' + input.categoryId,
    params
  );
```

My result contains the propertyIds but no property data. `properties` is null. What am I doing wrong? How do I get the property data?